# why is.na and !="" filter out the info differently

Tags: r

I have a df `df12` and I ran following codes on it. I thought the results should be the same but not. Could anyone tell me why? if TYN is na, should `is.na(TYN) belong to TYN!="Yes"` ?

```
df12<-structure(list(Test = c("OK", "NA", "NA", "NA"), TYN = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

df13<-df12 %>%
  mutate(Rel=case_when(Test %in% c("OK", "Good")~"Pass",
                       Test %in% c("NA") & TYN!="Yes"~"NA",
                       Test %in% c("Fail", "NA")~"Fail"))

df14<-df12 %>%
  mutate(Rel=case_when(Test %in% c("OK", "Good")~"Pass",
                       Test %in% c("NA") & is.na(TYN)~"NA",
                       Test %in% c("Fail", "NA")~"Fail"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TYN != 'Yes'` is not equal to `is.na(TYN)`.

In both the cases the second condition is what we are checking.

For the first case `TYN != 'Yes'` returns all `NA`s

```
df12$TYN != 'Yes'
#[1] NA NA NA NA
```

hence, the code goes to check the third condition which is `Test %in% c("Fail", "NA")`

```
df12$Test %in% c("Fail", "NA")
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Hence, you got `'Fail'` as output in first case.

For second case `is.na` works -

```
df12$Test %in% "NA" & is.na(df12$TYN)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Hence, you get output from second condition in this case which is `"NA"`.

Comment: When TYN==na, does it qualify TYN!="Yes"? Why it return"NA" instead of TRUE?

Comment: There is difference between `"NA"` and `NA`. `"NA"` is just string value but what you have in your data is real `NA`. Those `NA`'s can tested with `is.na(..)` and `!is.na(...)`.

Comment: So the real `NA` can only be test using `is.na()` and `!is.na()`, not any other way, right?

Answer (score 1):

The `NA`s are not real NA i.e. they are `"NA"`.  We could convert back with `type.convert`

```
library(dplyr)
type.convert(df12, as.is = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(Rel=case_when(Test %in% c("OK", "Good")~"Pass",
                       is.na(Test) & is.na(TYN)~"NA",
                       Test %in% c("Fail", "NA")~"Fail"))
```